# What's the point of setting object type as super class or interface in java

Tags: java, class, types

I've seen many times statements like this:

`List list = new ArrayList<String>();`

What's the point of writing like this? I mean setting the type of object a super class or implemented Interface of it. Is this makes a difference or improves performance or things like that?

### Note

My English is poor and I've probably written the question title and body confusing. Please edit that and then remove this line.

Comment: `List` is an **interface**, not a superclass.

Answer (score 0):

That statement means that you can use all of the features of `List` that are implemented using `ArrayList` but you could also use the features inside `LinkedList`. Although there is no harm if you have the object type as `ArrayList`, it could be useful for example, if you have a method that takes in a `List` parameter instead of an `ArrayList`, your choices have expanded and you can have other classes that implement that type, e.g `LinkedList`.

To put it simply, if you are using the interface `List` as its type, you are saying: "I want to use any class that does these things to do my own" as `List` is an interface. But if you just use `ArrayList`, you are saying: "I want to use just this specific class to to my things". In summary, it gives you more flexibility.

Other than that, there isn't much of a difference using the super class as the type or using `ArrayList` or other subclass as itself.

Hope that this is what you are asking about, and hope that it makes sense. If not, feel free to ask any questions.